# Array type 'char [n]' and 'uint8 [n]' is not assignable

Tags: c++, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm trying to convert two types of values: `char` and `uint8`.

I have a function `someFunction(TLabel *label, TEdit *edit)`. Inside of this function, I have a variable `char var[6+1]`.

What I'm trying to do:

Get an Alphanumeric text (input of `TEdit *edit`), convert this text and put it inside of the `var`.

I know that if I call this function and put the `*label` and the `*edit` I can get whatever I want, but the problem is the conversion to associate the text of `*edit` in the `var`.

An example of my code (inside of the function):

```cpp
char var[6+1];
label->Text = "Some text";
var = edit->Text;
    
//I will put var value inside of an another char (like a #define) that is in a struct, but doesn't matter for now
my_struct.valueOfVar = var;
```

And I have another function, it's the same code but the `valueOfVar` above is a `uint8`, and I can't convert it, too:

```cpp
uint8 valueOfAnotherVar[6+1];
```

Comment: You can't assign anything to static arrays. Consider using `std::array` if you need to assign a new value in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text` of a `TLabel` or `TEdit` is a `System::String`, which is an alias for `System::AnsiString` in C++Builder 2007 and earlier, and for `System::UnicodeString` in C++Builder 2009 and later.  You did not say which version you are using, but it makes a big difference in your example.

You can't assign *anything* directly to a fixed array, like `char[7]` or `uint8[7]`, by using `operator=` like you are attempting to do.  You will need to instead *convert and copy* the `String` data into the allocated memory of the arrays, eg:

```cpp
char var[6+1] = {};
label->Text = "Some text"; // OK - String has a constructor for 'const char*'

// if using CB2007 or earlier:
strncpy(var, edit->Text.c_str(), 6);

// if using CB2009 or later:
strncpy(var, AnsiString(edit->Text).c_str(), 6);
```

And then you can use one of these to copy the contents of `var` into `valueOfVar`:

```cpp
memcpy(my_struct.valueOfVar, var, 7);
```

```cpp
std::copy(var, var+7, my_struct.valueOfVar);
```

```cpp
std::copy_n(var, 7, my_struct.valueOfVar);
```

Comment: Directly to the point, good explanation, another question and another correct answer... It worked perfectly, thank you so much Remy!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with the types of the elements in the arrays, but rather that you simply can't assign one static array to another like this:

```
char a[7];
uint8 b[7];
a = b; // error
```

Instead, if you want to copy the values in the arrays, you can use `std::copy` like this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::begin(a));
```

---

If you have a dynamic array, you can still use `std::copy`, but you have to use the size of the array:

```
std::copy(b, b + N, a);
```

Make sure that both `a` and `b` point to at least `N` elements, otherwise you'll invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: But I'm not trying to assign char var[n] in a uint var[n] and vice-versa, I'm trying to put the text of edit->Text in a char var[n] and in a unit var[n].

Comment: Ok, you can still use `std::copy` though. Edited the answer.